# WPF and ADO.NET EF - error part II

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, prism, connection-string

I have added the connection string to the App.config of a main executable in my wpr, prism application and I get the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger' threw an exception.
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
  TypeName=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(Object message, ICollection`1 categories, Int32 priority, Int32 eventId, TraceEventType severity, String title, IDictionary`2 properties)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(Object message, String category, Int32 priority)
       at StockTraderRI.EnterpriseLibraryLoggerAdapter.Log(String message, Category category, Priority priority) in <my application>\EnterpriseLibraryLoggerAdapter.cs:line 28
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration) in <my application>\CAL\Desktop\Composite.UnityExtensions\UnityBootstrapper.cs:line 85
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run() in <my application>\CAL\Desktop\Composite.UnityExtensions\UnityBootstrapper.cs:line 69
       at StockTraderRI.App.RunInDebugMode() in <my application>\app.xaml.cs:line 44
       at StockTraderRI.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in <my application>\app.xaml.cs:line 34
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at StockTraderRI.App.Main() in <my application>\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
       Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
       Source=System.Configuration
       BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
       Line=0
       StackTrace:
       InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
            Message=Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (<my application>\bin\Debug\StockTraderRI.exe.Config line 7)
            Source=System.Configuration
            BareMessage=Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element.
            Filename=<my application>.exe.Config
            Line=7
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
                 at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
```

My App.conf looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.csdl|res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <configSections>

    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Also note - accept some of your historical answers as mentioned in another post - you need to click the tick to accept it as the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The inner exception quite clearly points to the error.  You need to change your app.config to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.csdl|res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://DataAccessLayer/EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```